# Matplotlib: Simplest possible example for 2 x 1 - grid of plots fails with "cannot create weak reference to bool"

Tags: python, matplotlib, multiple-axes

I'm trying to do the simplest possible 1-row, 2-column multi-ax-plot with matplotlib, actually [taken from the examples in the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html):

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplot(nrows=1, ncols=2, sharey=True)
```

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

    <ipython-input-9-4bc4f1ccd8e8> in <module>
          1 from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
    ----> 2 fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplot(nrows=1, ncols=2, sharey=True)


    ~/.virtualenvs/tcpsp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py in subplot(*args, **kwargs)
       1082 
       1083     fig = gcf()
    -> 1084     a = fig.add_subplot(*args, **kwargs)
       1085     bbox = a.bbox
       1086     byebye = []


    ~/.virtualenvs/tcpsp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py in add_subplot(self, *args, **kwargs)
       1365                     self._axstack.remove(ax)
       1366 
    -> 1367             a = subplot_class_factory(projection_class)(self, *args, **kwargs)
       1368         self._axstack.add(key, a)
       1369         self.sca(a)


    ~/.virtualenvs/tcpsp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_subplots.py in __init__(self, fig, *args, **kwargs)
         68 
         69         # _axes_class is set in the subplot_class_factory
    ---> 70         self._axes_class.__init__(self, fig, self.figbox, **kwargs)
         71         # add a layout box to this, for both the full axis, and the poss
         72         # of the axis.  We need both because the axes may become smaller


    ~/.virtualenvs/tcpsp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py in __init__(self, fig, rect, facecolor, frameon, sharex, sharey, label, xscale, yscale, **kwargs)
        471             self._shared_x_axes.join(self, sharex)
        472         if sharey is not None:
    --> 473             self._shared_y_axes.join(self, sharey)
        474         self.set_label(label)
        475         self.set_figure(fig)


    ~/.virtualenvs/tcpsp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/__init__.py in join(self, a, *args)
        923 
        924         for arg in args:
    --> 925             set_b = mapping.get(weakref.ref(arg), [weakref.ref(arg)])
        926             if set_b is not set_a:
        927                 if len(set_b) > len(set_a):


    TypeError: cannot create weak reference to 'bool' object



    <Figure size 432x288 with 0 Axes>
```

I honestly have no clue why it tries to create a weak reference to a `bool`.

I'm using fairly recent versions of matplotlib and Python:

```py
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

```
    3.7.0 (default, Sep 12 2018, 18:30:08) 
    [GCC 8.0.1 20180414 (experimental) [trunk revision 259383]]
```

```py
import matplotlib
matplotlib.__version__
```

```
    '3.0.2'
```

Am I right to assume that the example from the documentation should work? Is this a Matplotlib bug or have I done something wrong?

Comment: You confused `plt.subplot` with `plt.subplots`.

Comment: D'Oh. Yes. I feel very stupid.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's based on a simple spelling mistake instead of any real programming mistake.

Comment: I actually opened an issue for this, though, because I didn't see the typo when I looked at this, and the error message really is opaque, so I think a) this was a useful post, and b) matplotlib could do more here: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/15964

Comment: If the PR gets merged, this will now say `TypeError: subplot does not accept nrows and/or ncols kwargs.  Did you intend to call subplots()?`

Comment: I saw that the PR was merged - thanks a lot. I agree that in such a case of a likely mixup, the error message should be more helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, use `plt.subplots()`

It might be easier to not unpack your ax subplots variable until you want to customize each plot individually.

Usually how i'll do it is:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, dpi=175)

quadrants = 0, 1
```

so if I need to apply anything globally I can do:

```
for quad in quadrants:
    ax[quad]. (whatever)
```

and then individually:

```
ax[0].plot(...)
```

This also scales pretty well, such that if I was working with instead a 2x2 matrix of plots (like I am now), the difference is simply:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2, dpi=175)

quadrants = (0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)
```